# button's position changing when another button is shown

Tags: javascript, html, css

normally this isn't an issue, but since I've added the `.center-left` class the position of the first button (next) moves when the second button is shown. Is it because the center CSS is now applied to both buttons as a group instead of just the first button? How should I fix this?

```js
 
$('#btn-previous').hide()
$('#btn-next').click(function () {
    $('#btn-previous').show();
})
```

```css
.center-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;

  transform: translate(50%,100%);  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = 'center-left'>
    <input type="button" id='btn-next' value ="Next">
    <input type="button" id='btn-previous' value ="Previous">     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem because of 'absolute' position of parent element. don't use 'absolute' position or if you are force, set with of parent element.

```js
 
$('#btn-previous').hide()
$('#btn-next').click(function () {
     $('#btn-previous').show()
   
   
   })
```

```css
.center-left {

  transform: translate(50%,100%);

  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = 'center-left'>
<input type="button" id='btn-next' value ="Next">
     <input type="button" id='btn-previous' value ="Previous">
  
</div>
```

Comment: why does absolute positioning cause this?

Answer (score 0):

`Position absolute` doesn't cause any issue, that's because of `transform: translate(50%,100%);` in your code remove that and that works fine.

```
.center-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(50%,100%);/*remove this*/  
}
```